# gcc - argument "buf" doesn't match prototype

Tags: c, linux, gcc

in this function

```
    char *function(buf,salt)
    char *buf;
    char *salt;
    {
        function_body
    }
```

I get this error

```
error: argument "buf" doesn't match prototype
error: prototype declaration
argument "salt" doesn't match prototype
error: prototype declaration
```

This is the actual code:

```
    char * function(const char *, const char *);

    char *buffer = NULL;

    buffer = function(arg1, arg2);
```

Comment: How does your prototype look like?

Comment: What's the actual code and what's the actual error message? (Hint: actual error messages include file/line information.)

Comment: If you are trying to learn C, you picked the wrong book. What you're doing is pre-standard C. It's ancient and was used in 1980's. Get a newer book that deals with ANSI C.

Comment: I can clearly see that your prototype declares arguments `const`.

Comment: @becks Good, now what's the actual error message?

Comment: I fixed the error by removing constfrom the actual code.
I wasn't learning c, I had to use an old code in my program.
so this was the problem

Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a prototype declaration of `function()` somewhere and the actual function declaration does not match it. In your case the (type of the) parameters is different.

Usually, the errors show the location of the prototype. Look it up and compare it with your function declaration. The function arguments and their types must be *exactly* identical.

In your updated qustion you say that the prototype is defined as:

```
char * function(const char *, const char *);
```

So you also need to define your actual function as

```
char *function(const char *buf, const char *salt)
{
    // function_body
}
```

(It needs to be identical, so including the `const`-statements!)

Answer (score 2):

This means you have a declaration of the function somewhere, that is different.

Also, you shouldn't be doing "K&R-style" functions, that should be written:

```
char * function(char* buf, char *salt);
```

And most likely both arguments should be `const`, too.